# How can I link stackNavigator with tabsNavigtor?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a login screen in stackNavigator and when the user is logged in I need to show tabsNavigator instead.

I use firebase, in the render of my `index.ios` I have this condition after initializing firebase:

```js
if (this.state.islogged) {
    return <Tabs />;
} else {
    return <StackRegistro />;
}
```

The problem is that when I refresh or open the app, it always first shows the stackNavigator (first screen) For a small fraction of time before of showing the Tabnavigator

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "_when I refresh the app_"? And "_for some time_"?

Comment: yes, in the case with the live reload, too when i open the app.

Comment: For a small fraction of time

Comment: the app show the Tabnavigator

Comment: Do not stop showing stacknavigator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way for this is to add a loading screen or `ActivityIndicator` to it, for example:

```js
if (this.state.islogged === undefined)
    return <Loading />;
else if (this.state.islogged === true)
    return <Tabs />;
else
    return <StackRegistro />;
```

Make it specific `undefined` (or `null`) for network connection state.

Comment: thank you, in the constructor i had defined the state islogged  with false, y delete this and paste your code and its work!